# Heroku custom domain

Tags: heroku, dns

Would like to learn how website works.
Purchased a domain name  from bigrock domain registrar.
Am used to deploy applications to Heroku for my official websites.
But this is my personal site deployed to Heroku.

But how to connect my domain name to heroku ?
Heroku documentation is not clear to me.

I tried domain forwarding after playing with  google search, but my site http://www.prithvibhargav.com/ is still giving me blank page.

Where as the heroku default website address still works
http://afternoon-cove-8287.herokuapp.com/

How to make my domain name to connect to heroku and work ?

There are so many terminoliges people use which is confusing
CName , A address, 301 redirect, domain forwarding

Which one to choose ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your DNS to point to your heroku address. You should be able to go into the DNS settings in bigrock (where you registered the domain) and create CName record that will forward from your domain (http://www.prithvibhargav.com) to the heroku address (http://afternoon-cove-8287.herokuapp.com/)